# wxPython - Frame appears for a split second and disappears

Tags: python, wxpython

I have written a simple code to display a grid of buttons. But somehow upon execution the frame appears and disappears in a flash leaving behind an error that says :

**wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_hDWP" failed at ....\src\msw\window.cpp(5168) in wxWindow::EndRepositioningChildren(): Shouldn't be called**

There is a menu bar and a grid of buttons.Both the menu bar and grid of buttons are placed in the frame using a boxsizer.

I am not able to figure out how to get it working. Any help would be much appreciated.

[EDIT] : Removing the line *self.SetMenubar(menubar)* makes it work without the menubar

Here is my code :

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select("3.0")

import wx

class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):    
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        menu_1 = wx.Menu()
        menu_1.Append(-1,'Open','&Open')
        menu_1.Append(-1,'Save','&Save')

        menu_2 = wx.Menu()
        menu_2.AppendCheckItem(-1,'Sound On','&Sound On')

        menu_3 = wx.Menu()
        menu_3.Append(-1,'Help','&Help')
        menu_3.Append(-1,'About','&About')

        menubar.Append(menu_1,'File')
        menubar.Append(menu_2,'Settings')
        menubar.Append(menu_3,'Help')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar) ## REMOVING THIS MAKES IT WORK, BUT WITHOUT THE MENU BAR ##


        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        gsizer = wx.GridSizer(6,6,2,2)
        self.btn = range(36)

        for ix in range(0,36):
            self.btn[ix] = wx.Button(self,ix+1000,'Title',(10,10))
            gsizer.Add(self.btn[ix], 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=2)

        vsizer.Add(menubar,-1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        vsizer.Add(gsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=2)

        self.SetSizer(vsizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)


a = wx.App()
h = Main(None,-1,'App')
h.Show(True)
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: works fine for me in `wx 2.8.0` (I had to comment out the wxversion stuff...) ... also you may want to try `a=wx.App(redirect=False)` that way you will see any traceback messages in your console

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley. Ok I removed import wxversion (it compiles successfully) but the menubar is not visible. Any clues ?

Comment: nope like Jaime I only have 2.8 ... you could try 2.8 ... maybe something broke in 3.0 or someth8ing

Comment: Are you saying that it works with both the lines uncommented ?

**self.SetMenuBar(menubar)**
**vsizer.Add(menubar,-1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)**

Comment: @JoranBeasley Actually it does in 2.8, thanks !

Comment: oh thats probably your problem ... normally you dont add a menubar to any kind of sizer ... you just `SetMenuBar` and it takes care of the rest ... maybe 2.8 tolerates the error but in 3.0 they raise an error (a not very clear error I suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Joran Beasley was right: You should not add a menu bar to a sizer (what would that be supposed to do?), in contrast to a `wx.ToolBar`.

Just comment out

```
    # vsizer.Add(menubar,-1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
```

and it will work on 2.9.5 and 3.0.1b (and 3.0 also, I presume).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your indentation.  You need to construct the app outside of the body of the class.  In your example above, you've set it up as a class instance.  Just "dedent", err un-indent, these lines and it should work.

```
a = wx.App()
h = Main(None,-1,'App')
h.Show(True)
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I just fixed the indentation. Thanks for pointing out @jaimie , but my code had correct indentation in the IDE. That is not the source of this error sadly.

Comment: Sorry, I only have wx 2.8 locally, and it works there.

Comment: Yeah, just discovered.Thanks @jaime